# Why I am getting null reference exceptions if the list has a length and no null values in it?

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code, nothing fancy:

```
Modulo1.ForEach(t => fechasMaterias1.Add(t.Fecha.ToString("dddd d", culture)));
Modulo2.ForEach(t => fechasMaterias2.Add(t.Fecha.ToString("dddd d", culture)));
Modulo3.ForEach(t => fechasMaterias3.Add(t.Fecha.ToString("dddd d", culture)));
Modulo1.ForEach(t => horariosMaterias1.Add(t.HorarioInicio.ToString("hh\\:mm") + " a" + t.HorarioFin.ToString("hh\\:mm")));
Modulo2.ForEach(t => horariosMaterias2.Add(t.HorarioInicio.ToString("hh\\:mm") + " a" + t.HorarioFin.ToString("hh\\:mm")));
Modulo3.ForEach(t => horariosMaterias3.Add(t.HorarioInicio.ToString("hh\\:mm") + " a" + t.HorarioFin.ToString("hh\\:mm")));

//Modulo1
if (Modulo1.Count > 0)
{
    string dia = String.Empty;
    foreach (List<DateTime> item in diasMaterias1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                dia += "Horario del " + item.ElementAt(i).ToString("d \\de MMMM", culture) + " al ";
            else
                dia += item.ElementAt(i).ToString("d \\de MMMM", culture);

        }
        dias1.Add(dia);
    }
    Modulo1.ForEach(t => view_result1.Add(new HorariosModulosViewModel
    {
        NombreMateria = t.Nombre,
        ModuloNum = "Módulo " + NumerosModulos.Where(x => x.Equals(1)).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
        NombreModulo = ModulosNombre[0],
        Grupo = t.Grupo.ToString(),
        IdMateriasCursos = t.IdMateriasCursos

    }));

    for (int i = 0; i < dias1.Count; i++)
    {
        view_result1.ElementAt(i).dias = dias1.ElementAt(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < fechasMaterias1.Count; i++)
    {
        view_result1.ElementAt(i).diasMateria.Add(fechasMaterias1.ElementAt(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < horariosMaterias1.Count; i++)
    {
        view_result1.ElementAt(i).horarios.Add(horariosMaterias1.ElementAt(i));
    }
```

And previously I have initialized the lists like so: `List<string> fechasMaterias1 = new List<string>();` the same for `horariosMaterias1` and 2 and so on, however, I keep getting a null reference exception in the loops on fechasMaterias1 and horariosMaterias1. The strange thing is when I debug they both have a length of 20 (which I expect to, and none of them have null values). I'm completely lost, where may the source of this error come from. `view_result1` is a list of a standard POCO. By the way, I make sure `Modulo1` has a length and it's only supposed to have that length of 20 elements by now, so basically I'm just building lists from that main list "(Modulo1)" and they hve the same length, so why is the loop crashing?

Comment: So at what line the null reference exception is thrown?

Comment: When you debug this, which object is null?  If the exception is where you imply it is, there are at least 4 things on that line that could be null.  Find out which one it is.

Comment: At this line `for (int i = 0; i < fechasMaterias1.Count; i++)
                        {
                            view_result1.ElementAt(i).diasMateria.Add(fechasMaterias1.ElementAt(i));
                        }` the strange thing is that the previous line, which iterates through `dias1` runs ok, and they are identical (at least they should be, they aren't obviously or the error wouldn't show up) but like I said when I debug there are no null values in the list, they are just strings (repeated values by the way, maybe I should do a `Take` with linq, but I'll go to that once I solve this

Comment: I think there are actually three objects that may be null: `fechasMaterias1`, `view_result1` and `diasMateria` but they are all initialized and have even a count, `view_result1` is the list I'm adding to and is initialized, so that shouldn't be a problem, and `diasMateria` is a member of the POCO, why does the previous loop run ok then I wonder

Comment: ok this property is null `view_result1.ElementAt(i).diasMateria` but that's expected because it is the property member in the POCO, by the way the debugger seems to step once in the loop and then (apparently) in the second iteration it crashes, but I've noticed that's how the debugger is behaving because I'm using interop and the debugger seems to step twice in every line or at least take long to step over a line

Comment: And `view_result1` already has a length of 20 because I've already done a ForEach on it before

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post the code I made to solve the problem, I got rid of most of the classical foreach or for loops and made use of linq like follows:

```
//Modulo1
                List<string> aux1 = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < fechasMaterias1.Count; i+=4)
                {
                    aux1.Add(fechasMaterias1.ElementAt(i));
                }
                List<string> aux2 = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < fechasMaterias2.Count; i += 4)
                {
                    aux2.Add(fechasMaterias2.ElementAt(i));
                }
                List<string> aux3 = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < fechasMaterias3.Count; i += 4)
                {
                    aux3.Add(fechasMaterias3.ElementAt(i));
                }
                fechasMaterias1 = aux1;
                fechasMaterias2 = aux2;
                fechasMaterias3 = aux3;
                if (Modulo1.Count > 0)
                {
                    string dia = String.Empty;
                    foreach (List<DateTime> item in diasMaterias1)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
                        {
                            if (i == 0)
                                dia += "Horario del " + item.ElementAt(i).ToString("d \\de MMMM", culture) + " al ";
                            else
                                dia += item.ElementAt(i).ToString("d \\de MMMM", culture);

                        }

                    }
                    dias1.Add(dia);
                    Modulo1.ForEach(t => view_result1.Add(new HorariosModulosViewModel
                    {
                        NombreMateria = t.Nombre,
                        ModuloNum = "Módulo " + NumerosModulos.Where(x => x.Equals(1)).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
                        NombreModulo = ModulosNombre[0],
                        Grupo = t.Grupo.ToString(),
                        IdMateriasCursos = t.IdMateriasCursos

                    }));

                    for (int i = 0; i < dias1.Count; i++)
                    {
                        view_result1.ElementAt(i).dias = dias1.FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    view_result1.ForEach(t => t.diasMateria = fechasMaterias1);
                    var materiasListado1 = Modulo1.GroupBy(t=> t.IdMateriasCursos).ToList();
                    foreach(var item in materiasListado1) {
                    horariosMaterias1.Add(new Dictionary<int, string>() {{item.Key, (from U in item where U.IdMateriasCursos.Equals(item.Key) select U.HorarioInicio.ToString("hh\\:mm")+" a "+U.HorarioFin.ToString("hh\\:mm")).First()}});
                    }
                    view_result1.ForEach(t => t.horarios = horariosMaterias1.Where(p=> p.Keys.Contains(t.IdMateriasCursos)).ToList());
                    var maestrosListado1 = maestros1.GroupBy(t=> t.IdMateriasCursos).ToList();

                foreach(var item in maestrosListado1)
                {
                    losMaestros1.Add(item.Key, (from U in item where U.IdMateriasCursos.Equals(item.Key) select String.Join(" ", U.Titulo, U.Nombres, U.ApellidoPaterno, U.ApellidoMaterno)).ToList());
                }
                view_result1.ForEach(t => t.Maestros = losMaestros1.Where(x=> x.Key.Equals(t.IdMateriasCursos)).ToDictionary(r=> r.Key, v=> v.Value));
                }
```

that way I iterate faster, I get rid of repeated values and now there are no exceptions in the code. Thank you all!

Comment: One question, though, why is my question downvoted? Can't somebody have a doubt about a matter that programmers may face daily?